# htaccess redirect 4 specific pages to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem where I need to redirect 4 specific pages on my website to their https secure versions.

I currently have an htaccess file which is redirecting both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to `https://example.com`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R]
```

what I need is something like

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*example.com/page1.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*example.com/page2.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*example.com/page3.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*example.com/page4.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/page1.php$1 [R] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/page2.php$1 [R] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/page3.php$1 [R] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/page4.php$1 [R]
```

Notice that I have removed the third RewriteCond line from the above code as I don't want every page on my website to be displaying https only the pages I specifically state.

How can I resolve this problem?

PS also, is this line covering both www.example.com and example.com?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*example.com$ [NC]
```

I'm assuming that

```
^(.*\.)*
```

has something do with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (or any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php|page3\.php|page4\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 4):

I have modified and cleaned up your code. You can use this code in your .htaccess file in $DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# HTTPS is not already on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# Redirect to HTTPS is URI is page1.php OR page2.php OR page3.php OR page4.php
RewriteRule ^page[1234]\.php$ https://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply anubhava, I haven't tried your reply but it looks like ti would work. The only reason I didn't try yours first is that it seems you are using some kind of array for the page1.php, page2.php etc.

The problem with that way of doing it is I couldn't individually insert specific page names, for example my pages weren't actually called page1, page2 etc I was just using them for simplicity.

And unfortunately I do not know enough about rewriting to change it.

Anyway thanks again for your reply.

Comment: `[1234]` wasn't an array but regex way to say one of the 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. I would have used: `RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3|page4)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]` Anyway I think you accepted the right answer as @Gerben answered first and answered right :)