# Redirect specific pages to https using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to be able to redirect non https requests to specific pages to https. I am able to do this using the code I got from [htaccess redirect 4 specific pages to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633882/htaccess-redirect-4-specific-pages-to-https)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (or any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php|page3\.php|page4\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

But when the user clicks a link which is not one of those that requires https, I want to take them to non https page and not the https page. How can I do this?

That is if they click a link for page100.php on page1.php  it should go to http://domain.com/page100.php and not https://domain.com/page100.php

Comment: Question is: how do you define which pages to redirect and which not? The code you posted redirects exactly those 4 pages mentioned specifically. All other pages will _not_ be redirected.

Comment: As for the redirecting of the 4 pages it works the way I want it. My problem is that from those 4 https pages, a click to any page that is not one of those pages should be non https. But now, it continues with https.

Comment: That sounds like the issue is _not_ your rewriting rules. More like the links inside those pages delivered via https actually point to https pages again. Might be because they are _relative_ references or that some software that delivers the pages (a cms for example) creates https links. Note, that when referring from a page loaded via https to some page via the http protocol you will provoke warnings on the user side. Also things like javascript references often will not work due to security reasons. So what you ask for is questionable.

Comment: Yes, the links are relative and thats why I need help.

Comment: Well if the references are relative, then they point to the https server. Nothing rewriting can change about that. Either you have to construct http references instead (using the software generating those links or by changing static html pages), or you need to modify the targets on-the-fly on js level. You also could add further rewriting rules redirecting from https to http again, but that sounds insane. Question is: _why?_

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (or any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3|page4)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(page1|page2|page3|page4)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```