# Magento SSL Problems with Navigation Menu

Tags: php, magento, ssl, menu, categories

After activate SSL, i got error in my navigation Menu.

> Our Base URL: http: // www.mydomain.com
>
> Our Secure URL: https: // mydomain.com (without www)

Our Problem is: I stay in `my Account` (or) `view cart` (or) `checkout page`, after that I decide to go back to my category menu (fashion), so i click fashion menu in Main Navigation but it is going back home page (with Secure URL), not going to fashion menu pages. if i click company logo, it is going base URL. after that, i can go to fashion pages.

normally, we don't need to all activate SSL for pages. only login, my account and checkout page.

Anybody know how to solve problem? pls let advice me. Thanks.

Comment: Clear the cache ,index and check it.

Comment: already try it.. can't

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

have you try using some trick .htacess redirect?
basicly if you don't want using SSL for all page you can setup domain redirect using .htaccess after you add redirect code on htaccess you need erase cache on var/cache/

Comment: this is clear .htaccess method to redirect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633882/htaccess-redirect-4-specific-pages-to-https

Comment: Now, I already solved problem for menu becz of theme. Now i got another problem. unsecure url: http://www.example.com & secure url: https://example.com
after add to cart my product, it going to view cart page and try to checkout but can't checkout. so try to check in view-source code at Checkout button showing url is https://mydomain/onepage/. but can't checkout, stay in view cart page.
If i using chrome browser, after two (or) three time, it is going to checkout with ssl. if i using IE (or) mozilla, not going to checkout page.. sometime, showing is shopping cart is empty. and re-add again