# 2 out of 4 page WordPress site, requests are sent from HTTP. How can It be changed from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have seen some similar questions like these. But all of their answers are "how to change a whole site to HTTPS by creating a SSL certificate".

But in my case, I do have a SSL certificate and there are no problem for two pages. The other two pages are showing not secure icon and I think it is because of the request is send from http.

**How can I change it for specific pages? Can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 0):

**Add below code**

RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

// add page here you want to send from https

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/account/

RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Reference :
[htaccess redirect 4 specific pages to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633882/htaccess-redirect-4-specific-pages-to-https)